# Odd behavior when trying to cast varchar to decimal

Tags: mysql, string, casting, decimal

I have table with a column `mrr varchar(64)`. I can't change the type of the column.

This simple query:

```
select mrr, cast(mrr as decimal(10,2)) ass f_mrr
FROM projects
where mrr is not null and creator_fname='Lisa'
```

returns unexpected results.  Here is a partial list:

```
mrr         cast(mrr as decimal(10,2))
663.90      663.90
40.00       40.00
675.00      675.00
0.00        0.00
100.00      100.00
2,950.00    2.00
3,779.90    3.00
-8,482.00   -8.00
```

What's up with the last 3 rows?  I'm assuming it's the `CAST` that's doing this.

Can someone explain what's going on?
Why does it only do this for some rows and not others?

How can I reliably cast the `varchar(64)` to `decimal`?

Answer (score 4):

What's going on is a comma is *not* part of a valid number. MySQL stops parsing for a number at the first non "number" character.

When MySQL converts string to numeric, it converts only *leading* "number" chars, which comprise of optional leading sign, digits, optionally decimal point and more digits.

Everything else is truncated/ignored. This includes by the way, the whole string if it doesn't *start* with a "number".

You can try the following query:

```
select mrr, cast(trim(replace(mrr, ',', '')) as decimal(10,2)) as f_mrr
from projects
where mrr is not null and creator_fname = 'Lisa'
```

Comment: `SELECT CAST( REPLACE( mrr ,',','') AS DECIMAL(10,2))`

Comment: @spencer yeah that's what I had originally, but Tim clobbered it with what's there now. However, are you saying that using `trim()` *won't* work?

Comment: I am a moron :-(  Thanks for the help; I've been stuck on this for hours!

Comment: @Bohemian I added `TRIM()` out of paranoia, fearing that maybe the OP had unwanted leading/trailing whitespace, in addition to the comma problem, that's all.

Comment: @Tim yeah np. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
set @a = "295.00";
select if(right(@a,2)=00,CONCAT_WS('.',convert(@a,decimal(10,2))),@a)
```